# How to store formula,in function, as string to output later?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function in which I will store formulas for my converter. When X formula will be needed, it will be called from it. When trying it with simple **0:a+b**  it works when returning, but when trying to store it as string **meters_to_foots**, it doesn't work. I need to have that formula stored as something since I need to output it later.Here is a part of the code which I have problems with. **NameError: name 'meters_input' is not defined**

```
def my_formulas(i):
    switcher={
        0:(meters_input/0.3048)
    }

    return switcher.get(i,"Invalid formula")


distance_pick=input("Please pick one of the current convertions : \n \n1.Meters to X \n2.Inches to X \n3.Feets to X ")
    if(distance_pick=="1"):
        cls()
        distance_choice = input ("Please select which converter would you like to use ! : \n \n1.Meter to Foot \n2.Meter to Yard \n3.Meters to Inches ")
        if(distance_choice=="1"):
            meters_input=float(input("Make sure to enter distance in Meters ! : "))
            my_formulas(0)
            print ("\nYou entered", meters_input , "meters, which is equal to",my_formulas(0),"foots.")
            time.sleep (3)
            cls ()
            read_carefully_message()
```

Answer (score 1):

If these will always be simple functions you can use a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) expression for this:

```
def my_formulas(i):
    switcher= {
        0:lambda meters_input: meters_input/0.3048
    }

    return switcher.get(i,"Invalid formula")

my_formulas(0)(27) #88.58267716535433
```

If your function lookup will always be a number starting with zero you might be better off storing the functions as an array. You could do something like this as well:

```
def my_formulas(index):
    def meters2Feet(meters):
        return meters/0.3048

    def hours2Minutes(hours):
        return hours * 60

    def invalid(*args):
        return "Invalid formula"

    lookup = [
        meters2Feet,
        meters2Feet
    ]

    if index >= len(lookup):
        return invalid

    return lookup[index]



my_formulas(0)(27) # 88.58267716535433
```

It's a little more complicated, but probably easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for answering, now I keep getting You entered 1.0 meters, which is equal to <function my_formulas.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0535B420> foots.

Comment: @Renato you need to call the function with something  like: `my_formulas(0)(meters)` this gets function zero and calls it with the passed in meters.

Answer (score 1):

To create a function in Python use either lambda functions or the regular function definition. Examples are respectively:

```
def divide(meters_input):
  return meters_input / 0.3048
```

or

```
divide = lambda meters_input: meters_input / 0.3048
```

Generally the regular function definition is preferred since it improves readability. You can define your function mapping as follows:

```
def my_formulas(i):
    switcher={
        0:divide  # do not write divide()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function to this:

```
def my_formulas(i):
    switcher = (i/0.3048)

    return switcher
```

The "i" in the function is a local variable for the function. In your code you are passing 0 into the my_formulas() function. i then becomes 0, but meters_input is out of scope for the function.